# Custom Status Reason in Dynamics CRM 4

Tags: dynamics-crm, customization, dynamics-crm-4

In Dynamics CRM 4.0 I need to insert custom Status Reason for an Email Activity. By default it is not customizable.

I believe it is possible to do that by inserting values directly to MSCRM database tables.

I'm trying to figure out which tables are involved, but new values don't appear in Email activity customization.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't (at least via the UI).

Modifying the values in the database is not supported (See the article [Unsupported Customizations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928224.aspx)) and you really shouldn't do that.

<strike>In your case, I would introduce an additional field which represents your custom status.</strike>

You have the possibility to create a new status reason via the MetadataService. The description of  [EmailState Enumeration (CrmService)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959316.aspx) states that it is possible to modify the default values.

Comment: The following [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959316.aspx) says: _The values for e-mail status reason are customizable. The preceding table shows the values that are defined in a default installation._

Comment: @AlbertasA thanks for the hint. Give me some time to verify that. It is not possible to alter the values in the UI. The only possibility I see (because of your link), is to alter the values via the MetadataService.

Comment: Proposed solution by inserting status reason field via MetaDataServices worked for our needs. Thank You @ckeller !

Comment: @AlbertasA thank you for verifying! Sry, but I haven't had time for this yet.